# NativeBase card fitting/scaling the image within the card

Tags: react-native

First: I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29476165/image-resizing-in-react-native), but didn't find what I was looking for.

I wanna create something like this

[image]

But I have some problems with the resizing of an large image.. I found out that I can fix the pixels by doing inline style and using `height` and `width`. But I want it to look good on an iPad as well... What to do?

Here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Image } from 'react-native';
import { List, Card, CardItem, Thumbnail, Text, Button, Icon } from 'native-base';

class ListEquipment extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <List style={{padding: 5}}
        dataArray={this.props.items}
        renderRow={(item) =>

          <Card >
            <CardItem>
                <Thumbnail source={require('../img/Robot-96.png')} />
                <Text>Card</Text>
                <Text note>Bonus Info</Text>
            </CardItem>

            <CardItem cardBody>
                <Image source={require('../img/micscrope.jpg')} />
                <Text>
                    Information goes here..
                </Text>
                <Button >
                    <Icon name="ios-beer" />
                    <Text>Cheers</Text>
                </Button>
            </CardItem>
         </Card>

        }
      />
    )
  }
};

export default ListEquipment;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking to size the images based on the size of the device?

If so, you can use:

```js
import SCREEN_IMPORT from 'Dimensions'
  
const SCREEN_WIDTH = SCREEN_IMPORT.get('window').width,
const SCREEN_HEIGHT = SCREEN_IMPORT.get('window').height,
```

You will then be able to set the width/height inline as a percentage of SCREEN_HEIGHT and SCREEN_WIDTH.

Additionally you will want to consider the pixelRatio, it is recommended to store varying sizes of an image so that downsizing/upscaling will not effect image quality.

```js
var image = getImage({
  width: PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(200),
  height: PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(100),
});
<Image source={image} style={{width: 200, height: 100}} />
```

Where getImage will return the nearest sized image for the device screen/pixel ratio.

Answer (score 2):

First thing I would do is to wrap the `Image` on a `View`. Then, set a height that matches the aspect ratio of the image and then use `resizeMode: 'contain'`.

Anyway, this is the closest I could get:

```
<View style={{backgroundColor: 'green', margin: 10, borderColor: 'yellow', borderWidth: 2}}>
    <View style={{backgroundColor: 'green', padding: 10, borderBottomColor: 'yellow', borderBottomWidth: 2}}>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 20}}>Header</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
        <View style={{alignItems: 'center', height: 150}}>
            <Image source={require('./test.png')} style={{flex: 1, resizeMode: 'contain'}}/>
        </View>

        <View style={{backgroundColor: 'violet'}}>
            <Text style={{color: 'blue'}}>Description</Text>
        </View>
    </View>
</View>
```

With a 500x300(px) image this generates:

[image: screenshot]

By using an image with the correct aspect ratio it looks way better:

[image: screenshot correct aspect ratio]