# React Native - How to make image width 100 percent and vertical top?

Tags: react-native, image-resizing

I am newbie at react-native.
What I want to do is that fit an image in device and keep the ratio of image. Simply I want to make `width : 100%`

I searched how to make it and seems `resizeMode = 'contain'` is good for that.

However, since I used `resizeMode = 'contain'`, the image keeps the position vertically centered which I don't want.
I want it to be vertically top.

I tried to use a plug-in such as [react-native-fit-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fit-image) but no luck.

And I found [the reason why the image is not sizing automatically](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#why-not-automatically-size-everything).
But still I have no idea how to make it.

So, my question is what is the best way to deal with this situation?

Do I have to manually put `width, height` size each images?

I want :

- Keep image's ratio.
- Vertically top positioned.

React native test code :

https://snack.expo.io/ry3_W53rW

Eventually what I want to make :

https://jsfiddle.net/hadeath03/mb43awLr/

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at [react-native-scalable-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-scalable-image)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The image is vertically centered, because you added `flex: 1` to the style property. Don't add flex: 1, because that will fill the image to its parent, which is not desired in this case.

You should always add a height and width on an image in React Native. In case the image is always the same, you can use `Dimensions.get('window').width` to calculate the size the image should be. For example, if the ratio is always 16x9, the height is 9/16th of the width of the image. The width equals device width, so:

```js
const dimensions = Dimensions.get('window');
const imageHeight = Math.round(dimensions.width * 9 / 16);
const imageWidth = dimensions.width;

return (
   <Image
     style={{ height: imageHeight, width: imageWidth }}
   />
);
```

**Note: When using an implementation like this, your image will not automatically resize when rotating your device, using split screen, etc. You will have to take care of those actions as well if you support multiple orientations...**

In case the ratio is not the same, dynamically change the 9 / 16 by the ratio for each different image. If you don't really bother the image is a little bit cropped, you can use cover mode with a fixed height as well: (https://snack.expo.io/rk_NRnhHb)

```js
<Image
  resizeMode={'cover'}
  style={{ width: '100%', height: 200 }}
  source={{uri: temp}}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
So I have to know image size and use Dimensions in order to control image size.

Comment: In your expo example, why did you put width: '100%' ?
I don't think it's working.

Comment: 100% works only in newer versions of React Native (from 0.43 if I'm correctly)

Comment: Future visitors, using `Dimensions` will fail miserably when device is rotated. You need to bind orientation change and reverse width/height. This is not an elegant solution imo. RN should handle this better.

Answer (score 2):

Just to give this a shot as well

You can also wait for the Image onLayout callback to get it's layout properties and use that to update the dimensions. I created a component for that:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Dimensions, Image, ImageProperties, LayoutChangeEvent, StyleSheet, ViewStyle } from 'react-native';

export interface FullWidthImageState {
  width: number;
  height: number;
  stretched: boolean;
}

export default class FullWidthImage extends React.Component<ImageProperties, FullWidthImageState> {
  constructor(props: ImageProperties) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { width: 100, height: 100, stretched: false };
  }

  render() {
    return <Image {...this.props} style={this.getStyle()} onLayout={this.resizeImage} />;
  }

  private resizeImage = (event: LayoutChangeEvent) => {
    if (!this.state.stretched) {
      const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
      const height = width * event.nativeEvent.layout.height / event.nativeEvent.layout.width;
      this.setState({ width, height, stretched: true });
    }
  };

  private getStyle = (): ViewStyle => {
    const style = [StyleSheet.flatten(this.props.style)];
    style.push({ width: this.state.width, height: this.state.height });
    return StyleSheet.flatten(style);
  };
}
```

This will update the dimensions of the image to match the width of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

You can Apply this style to image:
If you apply `imageStyle` to the `Image` tag then the Image width will be 100% and Image height will be 300.

```
imageStyle:{
height:300,
flex:1,
width:null
}
```

Suppose you Image Code is:

```
<Image style={imageStyle} source={{uri:'uri of the Image'}} />
```

Comment: When I added null, it made the image go away.

Answer (score 2):

You can Apply this style to image: If you apply **Image** to the Image tag then the Image width full image.

```
const win = Dimensions.get('window');
export default function App() {
  
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>

       <Image
       style={{
        width: win.width/1,
        height: win.width/5,
        resizeMode: "contain",
        alignSelf: "center",
        borderRadius: 20,
      }}
        source={require('./assets/logo.png')}
      />


    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click on you image to get resolution. In my case 1233 x 882

```
const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');

const ratio = 882 / 1233;

    const style = {
      width,
      height: width * ratio
    }

<Image source={image} style={style} resizeMode="contain" />
```

That all

Answer (score 0):

I have a component that takes image props and does the proper adjustments (and works within a `ScrollView` and with `require`d assets.  Inside a scroll view it uses the height of the image as the height regardless if it is scaled that causes some excess padding.  This component performs size computations and readjusts the image style to work with a 100% width preserving the aspect ratio of the file that was loaded.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Image, ImageProps } from "react-native";

export function FullWidthImage(props: ImageProps) {
  // Initially set the width to 100%
  const [viewDimensions, setViewDimensions] = useState<{
    width?: number | string;
    height?: number | string;
  }>({
    width: "100%",
    height: undefined,
  });

  const [imageDimensions, setImageDimensions] = useState<{
    width?: number;
    height?: number;
  }>(() => {
    if (typeof props.source === "number") {
      // handle case where the source is an asset in which case onLoad won't get triggered
      const { width, height } = Image.resolveAssetSource(props.source);
      return { width, height };
    } else {
      return {
        width: undefined,
        height: undefined,
      };
    }
  });
  return (
    <Image
      onLayout={(e) => {
        // this is triggered when the "view" layout is provided
        if (imageDimensions.width && imageDimensions.height) {
          setViewDimensions({
            width: e.nativeEvent.layout.width,
            height:
              (e.nativeEvent.layout.width * imageDimensions.height) /
              imageDimensions.width,
          });
        }
      }}
      onLoad={(e) => {
        // this is triggered when the image is loaded and we have actual dimensions.
        // But only if loading via URI
        setImageDimensions({
          width: e.nativeEvent.source.width,
          height: e.nativeEvent.source.height,
        });
      }}
      {...props}
      style={[
        props.style,
        {
          width: viewDimensions.width,
          height: viewDimensions.height,
        },
      ]}
    />
  );
}
```

This is to compensate for `contain` which adds extra padding around the image (which is basically making the image view height full) even if the image width is `100%`.

Note chances are you are trying to put it in as a background, in which case `ImageBackground` does not renders correctly on Android.  Using the above code a few tweaks I created the following that renders things correctly with long and short text.

```
import React, { PropsWithChildren } from "react";
import { ImageProps, View } from "react-native";
import { FullWidthImage } from "./FullWidthImage";

export function FullWidthImageBackground(props: PropsWithChildren<ImageProps>) {
  const imageProps = { ...props };
  delete imageProps.children;
  return (
    <View>
      <FullWidthImage
        {...imageProps}
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
        }}
      />
      {props.children}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Note if you are using it with a header, you need to add a padding view as the first child

```
<View
  style={{
    height: safeAreaInsets.top + (Platform.OS === "ios" ? 96 : 44),
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to not define height for the image and set the width to `100%`. But, its necessary to set `resizeMode` to `contain`. See example below:

```js
<View>
  <Image source={require('../../../assets/stools/type1.png')} resizeMode="contain"  style={{width: '100%'}}/>
</View>
```

This way the aspect ratio is preserved.

[image]

To remove the extra space above and below the image, you can set `height: 100` or any other number. This will not affect the aspect ratio`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method to fill container without any margin

```js
const ImageHandler = ({ name, onPress }: any) => {
  const [ImgHeight, setImgHeight] = React.useState(width)
        
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      activeOpacity={1}
      onPress={() => onPress()}
      style={{
        width: width,
        height: ImgHeight,
        maxHeight:width,
      }}
    >
      <FastImage
        onLoad={(e) => {
          let newWidth =  width
          let hei = (e.nativeEvent.height/ e.nativeEvent.width)*newWidth
          setImgHeight(hei)
        }}
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          width: undefined,
          height: undefined,
          backgroundColor: colors.white,
        }}
        resizeMode={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "cover" : "cover"}
        source={{ uri: `${Your image url}` }}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```